# Java DOM trim white space in XML file

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I'm using DOM parer with Java.
This is my simple xml file with who I will introduce my issue:

```
<class>
    <student rollno="393">
        <firstname> Some Name </firstname>
        <lastname>Some Family</lastname>
        <nickname>dinkar</nickname>
        <marks>85</marks>
        <address>
            <street>Some Street</street>
            <number>71</number>
        </address>
    </student>
</class>
```

This is my part from java code with who I have tried to parse my xml file:

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("student");

            for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++)
            {

                Node n = nList.item(i);
                Element e = (Element)n;;

                if(e.getAttribute("rollno").equals("393")){
                    log.debug(e.getFirstChild().getNodeName().trim());
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to get first child node from my xml. But when I run program I received the result #Text. This is because of space between student and first name elements.
How can I trim this space and receive result firstname.

Thanks for the time spend for my issue.

Comment: Nodes are not just elements;  they include the entire document structure, including the whitespace between elements.  Have a look at [all the subclasses of Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html).  However, Element does have its own [getElementsByTagName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagName-java.lang.String-) method which returns only elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [VGR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831987/vgr) for the help. There is the correct source for my issue.

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("student");

                for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++)
                {

                    Element e = (Element)nList.item(i);

                    if(e.getAttribute("rollno").equals("393")){
                        log.debug(e.getFirstChild().getNodeName().trim());
                    }
                }
            }
```